# Methanol adducts with CaCl2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Methanol forms adducts with $\ce{CaCl2}$ but I am not finding much information about the nature of these adducts & their stability. Are these solid adducts? Crystalline?  Is the reaction substantially exothermic etc.?

In [this link](http://www.tetrachemicalseurope.com/resources/physical_properties/solids.aqf), it is written that:-

> At temperatures below 55°C, $\ce{CaCl2}$ forms $\ce{CaCl2·4CH3OH}$ with methanol and below 55°C, $\ce{CaCl2·3CH3OH}$ is formed.

Obviously, they seem to have gotten their Temperatures wrong. Any more authoritative information about methanol adducts?

Comment: Yes, they are solid, crystalline, and moderately exothermic.