# Why can't I dry/concentrate ethanol using calcium chloride ... or can I?

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, erratum

My (very unreliable) school textbook tells me:

> Lower alcohols form a solid derivative with certain metal salts.

and,

> It is for this reason that ethanol cannot be dried/concentrated using anhydrous calcium chloride.

---

*Nowhere* else in the book, is there any reference to this supposed reaction between a lower alcohol (ethanol) and a metal salt (calcium chloride). So I couldn't read more about this from there...

Googling wasn't much help; though I *did* find [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01656a048?journalCode=jacsat) that seems to concur with my textbook (albeit, with more detail) ... the paper is dated all the way back to **1923**, so I suspect the modern Chemist's view of the matter would be different (the paper makes use of the term "alcoholate", [which no longer carries the same meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcoholate)).

---

Question:

**Does ethanol really react with calcium chloride to form some "solid derivative"?**

Additionally,

**Do lower alcohols (methanol and ethanol to name a few) really react with "metal salts" (textbook didn't specify, so i would use the following examples: copper sulfate and magnesium chloride)?**

Comment: You understand what happens with water when CaCl2 absorbs it? Why wouldn't ethanol do the same?

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040603181801475

Comment: @Curt That confirms the ethanol- $CaCl_2$ "solid derivative". Know anything about ethanol/methanol reacting with *other* metal salts? Thanks  again for the link! O:)

Comment: Strongly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54878/methanol-adducts-with-cacl2

Comment: @Nilay Yep, *very* strongly related :D

Comment: I am guessing that the correct answer to this question would be "CaCl2 is rather soluble in dry ethanol". Like so many other inorganic salts that are used to easily dry unpolar solvents.

Comment: https://youtu.be/RGG2GNvpwA4?t=438 also claims that calcium chloride forms a complex with ethanol.

Answer (score 2):

The apparent answer is yes, to quote from a source (composed from [extracts of old chemistry journal](http://calcium.atomistry.com/calcium_chloride.html)):

> Calcium chloride forms addition compounds with the alcohols. On evaporating a solution in ethyl alcohol at a low temperature rectangular plates of $\ce{2CaCl2.7C2H5OH}$ are deposited. The compounds $\ce{CaCl2.3C2H5OH}$ and $\ce{CaCl2.CH3OH}$ have also been separated, as well as a mono- and a di-acetone compound, and compounds with isobutyl and amyl alcohols.

So, if you are working with a cold solution of $\ce{C2H5OH}$ with $\ce{CaCl2}$ exposed to air undergoing evaporation, it is possible to form an addition compound (taking the form of rectangular plates) with the formula, $\ce{2CaCl2.7C2H5OH}$ or $\ce{CaCl2.3C2H5OH}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that lower alcohols cannot be dried using $\ce{CaCl2}$ as they form stable complexes with it but higher alcohols can be dried using $\ce{CaCl2}$ as they form unstable complexes while water forms stable complex. On the other hand,
aromatic alcohols like phenols can't be dried using $\ce{CaCl2}$ as they are somewhat acidic in nature.

At the same time, I assume that all salts wouldn't do the same thing with lower alcohols as each salt-alcohol complex has its own degree of stability and the salt-water complex may be more stable than the former. So, I don't recommend $\ce{CuSO4}$ as a drying agent.